# nodejs awaiting multiple promises, where to do catch() and then() blocks

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await

I have a function that should do a few things simultaneously. For that I call to other functions that return a Promise, like so:

```js
async function do_things(params){
    return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
        const first_promise=perform_first(params);
        const second_promise=perform_second(params);

        let [first_result,second_result]=await Promise.all([first_promise,second_promise]);
        ...
        resolve();
    });
}
```

That should pretty much do the trick. Now I want to add .then(res) and .catch(err) blocks to log both 'res' and 'err'.

Should I do that on `do_first(params).then((res)=>{...}).catch((err)=>{...});`
or on `first_result.then((res)=>{...}).catch((err)=>{...});`?
(obviously the second can be done likewise)

Comment: [What is the explicit promise construction antipattern and how do I avoid it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743) | [Is it an anti-pattern to use async/await inside of a new Promise() constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43036229)

Comment: elaborating on that, the function just being `return Promise.all([first_promise,second_promise])` will probably do what you need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understood from your post:

What you are trying to do looks exactly like the use case of [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)
or [`Promise.allSettled()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/allSettled) which thy both return promises, so no need to wrap it with `new Promise..`

If you want to perform something that requires both promises to be resolved you can do:

```
async function do_things(params) {
  const first_promise = perform_first(params);
  const second_promise = perform_second(params);

  return Promise.all([first_promise, second_promise]);
}

// somewhere else in your code
try {
    await do_things(params)

    // do things if both promises are resolved
} catch (error) {
    // well, you know 
}
```

Or if need to run both tasks and then resolve the promise from `do_things` anyways you may use `Promise.allSettled` which unlike `Promise.all` it doesn't reject once one of your promises is rejected

```
async function do_things(params) {
  const first_promise = perform_first(params);
  const second_promise = perform_second(params);

  return Promise.allSettled([first_promise, second_promise]);
}

// somewhere else in your code
const things = await do_things(params)

things.forEach(something => {
    if (something.status === "fulfilled") {
        console.log(something.value);
    } else { // status is "rejected"
        console.error(something.reason)
    }
});
```